# Como somar valores de uma coluna em Ruby/RoR

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Beleza?

Estou tentando construir uma aplicação em Rails. Nela possuo um recurso onde os usuários informam o **tempo de execução** relacionado a uma **categoria**. Bem, preciso realizar a somar  o total do tempo da coluna **tempo de execução** para poder apresentar a um determinado usuário: *"Você já realizou um total de X horas de atividades"*.

Outro ponto é que fiz o relacionamento com o model **Category** pelo atributo **category_id** e tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, só que gostaria de fazer com que aparecesse no form através de uma lista de categorias (pelo nome) e não fazer com que o usuário digite o **id da categoria** para fazer o relacionamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Soma e outras funções de agregação

Para somar valores através da [API `ActiveRecord`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html), utilize o método [`sum()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum). Exemplo:

```ruby
Person.sum('age')
```

## Lista de opções

Sobre o segundo ponto, para exibir um elemento `select` (Combo Box) e facilitar a seleção, você pode utilizar o `collection_select`. Exemplo retirado do [item 3.3 da guia](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html):

```ruby
<%= collection_select(:person, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
```

No trecho acima:

- `:person` é uma referência ao *model*
- `:city_id` é o atributo que faz o relacionamento
- `City.all` é a lista dos possíveis valores do relacionamento
- `:id` é o valor de cada item da lista (o `:id` selecionado será atribuído para `:city_id`)
- `:name` é o *label* a ser exibido na combo para cada item

---

**Atualização**

O valor do campo pode não estar sendo atualizado no modelo. Uma [causa provável](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903228/rails-collection-select-not-saving) é não ter definido o atributo como acessível.

Exemplo Rails 3:

```ruby
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id
```

Exemplo rails 4:

```ruby
class ItemsController <  ApplicationController
  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:category_id)
  end
```

Comment: Olá @utluiz, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Estou tendo um pequeno problema na Lista de opções, no meu caso o relacionamento se dá pela categoria, então fiz:                `<%= collection_select(:person, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>`, mas ao enviar o form ele informa que o campo Category não pode ficar em branco, mesmo eu tendo selecionado uma categoria. Como devo fazer? PS.: Esqueci de falar que estou iniciando no RoR.

Comment: @user5476 Vou atualizar a resposta com algumas sugestões do que pode ser.

Comment: Beleza então. Brigadão pela ajuda!

Comment: Analisei o log e vejo que ele não está salvando devido o person mesmo. Daí tentei ajustar no controller mas não funcionou `params.require(:exercice).permit(:timer, :date, { person: [:category_id] })`

Comment: Muito obrigado @utluiz! Sua ajuda foi essencial. Abraço!

Comment: @user5476 Ainda bem que conseguiu. Desculpe não ter respondido mais, mas estava tudo corrido no trabalho. Abraço.